# The jQuery Datepicker maxDate doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a problem with jQuery and my datepicker.

I've got this:

```
$(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      minDate: '02/16/2012',
      maxDate: '04/15/2017',
      buttonImage:"calendar.gif"
    });
});
```

When I go on my datepicker, the `minDate` work, the `maxDate` is set (I check it on console) but the `maxDate` is not respected, I can choose a day after my `maxDate`.

EDIT : sorry for your time, it was just the data which were wrong, it was in the dd/mm/yy format so it's normal that it doesn't work, with good data it work as describe in jquery API documentation

Comment: It all depends which datepicker you are using...

Comment: What's that `04/15/2017`? Are you passing a string instead `'04/15/2017'`?

Comment: 02/16/2012 could be attempting to apply division to these numbers.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to use quote, it's a work project and I can't put the exact code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to look like the example in my fiddle and everything should work for you.

[SEE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/c9wk3cyd/)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        minDate: "02/16/2012",
        maxDate: "04/15/2017",
        buttonImage:"ui-icon-calendar"
});

<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

The min and max date properties take strings or variables, so wrap the dates in quotes, then remove the semi colon from the last property.

Also take a look at the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: It was just a mistake, I use string in my code, that's why I dont understand why it doesn't work

Comment: @Alann Take a look at the working fiddle, compare it carefully with your code, are you missing the proper includes? You need jquery js files, jquery ui js files and the jquery ui css files.

Comment: I've got all of them ... and it's more weird than that, because I can see with the console that the datepicker maxDate is set, but I can tank a date after maxDate but not all date, it stop at 2021 and not at 3000 like when there is no maxDate ...

Comment: @Alann Is your site/code public so I can look at it for you? If not then I would study the fiddle and compare to your code. The date picker definitely works, so I am guessing your code is flawed. Maybe you can post more of it or even better you can prepare a demo using fiddle or codebin that reproduces the behavior you are experiencing?

Comment: the code is a bit more complicated than that, because I import the date with a perl script, I'm not at work anymore I'll send you more code thursday